# Getting 403 AJAX error on second call jquery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a simple form with a select field of clients. Once you select a client, i am making an ajax call to fetch the clients logo and display below the select field for the user to see. This works fine. The AJAX request looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/clients/access_controls/<?php echo basename(__FILE__);?>',
  type: 'post',
  data: clientId,
  //dataType: 'application/json',
  //contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',

  error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
    alert('ERROR MESSAGE: ' + errorMessage);
    return false;
  },

  success: function(d) {
    $(d.html).insertAfter(tab.find('table tr:eq(0)'));
    var func = d.responseScript;
    if ($.isFunction(eval(func))) {
      eval(func + '()');
    }
  }
});
```

The problem is, once i select another client from the list, the Ajax call returns an error of 403 FORBIDDEN. What could be the issue? What baffles me is the first call goes fine, so why does it fail the second time. Its a very simple issue, but i have not been able to fix it. I have tried setting different content types with the request, and also tried setting "Access-Control" headers on the PHP file processing the request like so:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
//header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'api-key,content-type');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
//header('content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
```

to no avail. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here's the php CODE

```
if (isset($_POST['request'])) {
  if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    //header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'api-key,content-type');

    //header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    //header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
    //header('content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

}

switch ($_POST['request']) {
    case 'logos':
        if (!isset($_POST['sub'], $_POST['value'])) {
            echo json_encode([
                'error' => 'Invalid arguments'
            ]);
            exit;
        }

        $logo = getClientLogo($_POST['value']);
        $html = '<tr><td valign="top">Current Logo:</td><td valign="top" class="client_logo">' . ((!empty($logo)) ? $logo : '<strong>No Logo</strong>') . '</td></tr><tr><td>Upload new logo:</td><td><form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="member_image" action="/clients/access_controls/' . basename(__FILE__) . '"><input type="file" name="member_image" class="hidden" /><input type="button" value="Select File" data-usage="member_image" data-event="click" data-label="member_filename" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="member_filename">No file selected</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Upload &amp; Save &gt;" /><input type="hidden" name="request" value="image_upload" /><input type="hidden" name="value" value="' . $_POST['value'] . '" /><input type="hidden" name="iil_token" value="' . getCSRFToken() . '" /></form><input name="member_image" style="display: none;" /></td></tr>';
        print json_encode([
            'html' => $html,
            'responseScript' => 'IIL.applyImageUploadRequirements'
        ]);
        exit;
```

Comment: Did you properly inspect those xhrs in the browser console? Including the URLs, parameters, responses?

Comment: Where is the client-side part, where you change what `clientId` contains?

Comment: 403 means you dont have acces, did you check the echo basename(__FILE__) ?

Comment: "Access-Control" headers are used for [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), nothing to do with 403 Forbidden errors. Your request doesn't appear to be a CORS request. So that won't help. More likely something else in the code is causing the 403. Show the PHP logic which processes this request, please

Comment: Setting any `Access-Control` headers is a fruitless endeavor, you are not making a cross-origin request here in the first place.

Comment: @Grumpy OP states it works for one clientID but not another. So the file permissions are unlikely to be the issue I would guess.

Comment: @Ayson, i dont know how the names of the logo's are formatted,if it works for one it should work for all, unless they are in different dirs of have weird chars in name.

Comment: @Grumpy the PHP code could easily return a 403 response programmatically, e.g. the user doesn't have permission to view that specific client ID. (And there might be no real logo files anywhere, it could all be the database for all we know.)

Comment: @ADyson that's right, the first request works so it could not be a permissions issue. That's what is confusing about it lol

Comment: @GustavFN Well if you show us the PHP code which is being executed, and an example of what the response is supposed to look like, we might have a better chance of helping you diagnose it.

Comment: There is no use of any DB at this point, the PHP file grabs the images from the same folder, and the filenames are formed from the clientIds. If that helps

Comment: No, it doesn’t. Show us relevant code already.

Comment: @misorude I can confirm for sure that the script returns the error even before hitting the PHP script. The forbbidden error in my developer tools points to a jquery core file. The section in jquery throwing the exception goes something like so:   !c.crossDomain&&!e["X-Requested-With"]&&(e["X-Requested-With"]="XMLHttpRequest");try{for(h in e)i.setRequestHeader(h,e[h])}catch(j){}i.send(c.hasContent...                                                                                                                                                    It would appear its to do with request headers?

Comment: `The problem is, once i select another client from the list, the Ajax call returns an error of 403 FORBIDDEN.` What does this mean? You do another GET request (basically reload the page?) for the newly selected client?

Comment: _“I can confirm for sure that the script returns the error even before hitting the PHP script”_ - that makes very little sense. You can hardly get a 403, if no actual HTTP request happened in the first place.

Comment: @MateiMihai its a post request, and the AJAX  call fires off on an onChange event on the select field

Comment: @misorude well it could be generated by the webserver rather than the PHP interpreter. But I agree I don't think that's what is being said here.

Comment: @GustavFN Javascript/jQuery cannot return a 403 response directly. It must come from the server, as the result of a HTTP request. So pointing to a line in your jQuery file doesn't really add much in terms of diagnosis. Looking at the Network tab in your browser while the request is running would give you more useful info. So would showing us the PHP code, as requested multiple times already. Not sure why you are so unwilling to do that.

Comment: Im very curious what causes this

Comment: @misorude that is because i put a die() right after the PHP script checks for the $_POST value, and it seems the 403 error is triggered before getting there. Weird i know.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your advice, i hesitated because the PHP script is a bit convoluted and does a lot of other stuff. I felt it would be difficult to read. I'm just trying to fix that little part of one of the many things the code does. There's the code i have extracted the bit and added it to the question. Cheers.

Comment: Your PHP code appears to expect multiple POST parameters of different names there, but all we know about what you are actually sending, is still `data: clientId`. We have no idea what that actually contains …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who might find this beneficial, @Dylan Hamilton-Foster i would say you were close-as in, it was a security check issue. However, my specific situation was unique. Here's the thing; in our in-house framework, we fire a csrf code generated from the same page with every form submitted, and check for it in the processing script. When one first visits the page, the csrf code is sent and so it matches and the request is allowed through. But because the second form submission happens without the page refreshing, no csrf is sent through and so the csrf verification script on the processing side rejects the request.

My solution was basically to set a counter variable and post it with every request (alongside the csrf token) and then increment it on subsequent requests. In the processing script, i modified the token verification to accept the counter variable if it is present.

I know this is unsafe and defeats the purpose of using a CSRF token, but

a) this app was only used internally, and was within our corporate firewall

b) this was a legacy application with the same script being used by multiple other in-house applications, so i wanted to make the least change possible.

There you go. It worked well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Mod Security - try turning it off & see if that works. I recently had trouble getting 403 errors from an ajax call to a php script - it would give a 403 if the content contained the word 'include'. Turning off mod-security got it working until we found the rule that was at fault.